# GitLab runner runs first two commands and says "build succeeded"

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, gitlab, continuous-integration

I'm using GitLab's "CI Multi-Runner", which I have installed on Windows 2012 R2 instance. Builds start correctly and begin to run, but the build is marked as complete before it even runs my entire script.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
build_web:
  script:
    - cd Web
    - npm install
    - jspm install
    - gulp build
```

Upon pushing, the pipeline runs through `npm install` and then outputs "Build succeeded" and ends the build successfully (having skipped the following two commands).

Answer (score 2):

I've been having these early exit issues on GitLab CI with Windows with NodeJs / NPM commands. I solved it using PowerShell to wrap the commands in place of directly calling NPM

replacing:

```
- npm install
```

with:

```
- powershell -Command "Start-Process npm -ArgumentList install -Wait"
```

In my case I needed to run grunt as well which caused the same issue so similarly wrapped like

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process grunt -ArgumentList autobuild -Wait"
```

Hope that works for you
Toby

Comment: You might have a better experiance switching the runner to use PowerShell rather than cmd. in the config.toml file in the directory the runner resides in add

Comment: `shell = "powershell"` below the `executor = "shell"` line

Comment: @tobyd, do you have any idea why these early exists are happening?
I had the same issue and it helped, thanks!

Comment: @Olexander, No problem - Glad it helped. I'm not sure why this occurs, npm seems to be tripping up GitLab runner in a way it doesn't upset PowerShell. I've found PowerShell a more flexible shell for my process anyway as it can manage UNC paths.

Comment: @Olexander, came across this - seems like its just a gitlab processor thing https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-ci-not-running-script-strings/4845 looks like you just need to run npm as `npm install --silent` to prevent it exiting early.

Answer (score 2):

Change `npm install` to `call npm install`. This is how the Windows shell works, if you don't use `call` it will execute in the same context and then exit after running.